# Task modules with adaptive cards in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, dark-theme

I use adaptive card in the task module, however it looks very strange in the dark theme of Microsoft Teams (white background). How can this problem be corrected?

Schema version 1.3 (example):
AdaptiveCard adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 3));

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2JyV.png)

P.S.

Example card in json format:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "text": "YouTrackBot помощь"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Это базовая страница по YouTrackBot, подробная информация расположена в соответсвующих разделах.",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.ShowCard",
      "card": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.3",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "large",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "text": "Как получить свой токен YouTrack?"
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "1) Зайти в свой профиль YouTrack;",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "2) Во вкладке 'Общее' выбрать 'Обновление анкетных данных и управление логинами';",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "3) Перейти во вкладку 'Аутентификация';",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "4) Далее нажимаем на кнопку 'Новый токен';",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "5) В окне создания токена важно, чтобы были указаны области 'YouTrack' и 'YouTrack Administation', имя - произвольное;",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "6) После - нажимаем создать и копируем токен (Внимание! Посмотреть токен возможности больше не будет, поэтому его лучше сохранить в удобном для себя месте).",
            "wrap": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "title": "Как получить токен"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.ShowCard",
      "card": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.3",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "large",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "text": "Как настроить YouTrackBot?"
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Сперва необходимо изучить, как получить свой токен (инструкция есть у бота);",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Разобравшись с токеном можно приступать к настройке, она делается просто, за несколько шагов;",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "1) Первый шаг - необходимо указать URL YouTrack'а, который планируется использовать;",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "2) Второй шаг - необходимо указать уже известный токен;",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "3) Третий шаг - нажать кнопку 'Подтвердить';",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Если все хорошо, цвет текста станет зеленым и это означает, что подключение настроено;",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Если возникнет ошибка, то появится соответствующая надпись, которая означает, что URL и/или токен введены с ошибкой и бот не смог подключиться к YouTrack.",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "(Внимание! Варианты URL формата: <https://example.myjetbrains.com>/<example.myjetbrains.com>/<example.myjetbrains>)",
            "wrap": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "title": "Как настроить приложение"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.ShowCard",
      "card": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.3",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "large",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "text": "Как использовать YouTrackBot?"
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Создание задачи из сообщения:",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "1) Необходимо навести на сообщение, нажать на троеточие в правом верхнем углу",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "2) Выбрать 'Дополнительные действия'",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "3) В новом списке нужно выбрать 'Создать новую задачу в YouTrack'",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "4) В открытой форме нужно выбрать проект, где будет созадана задача, и нажать продолжить",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "5) Заголовок и описание заполняются сами, но Вы можете их отредактировать",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "6) Длаее необходимо заполнить обязательные поля для задачи и по желанию заполнить оставшиеся поля, которые для создания задачи не обязательны",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "7) Нажать кнопку 'Создать'",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "8) Если задача была успешно создана, в чате, в предпросмотре сообщения, появится карточка, которая содержит краткую информацию о задаче и ссылку на YouTrack",
            "wrap": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "title": "Как работать с приложением"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you send the payload of your card?

Comment: @TimCadenbach Hi! Added to post.

Comment: @Gromovoy Maxim, We tried to repro it at our end and its looking fine in dark mode. Could you please try to upgrade your MS teams version and check if it helps? FYI we have tested in MS Teams Version 1.4.00.30066

Comment: hmm thats indeed weird...wanted to double check you don't have any background colors set on the card which you don't tho. If i test the card with AppStudio its perfectly fine here :( might be something your bot is doing differently?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I am using version 1.4.00.31569. Moreover, the problem is relevant both with the desktop version of Microsoft Teams and in the web version :(
Everything is displayed correctly from the mobile application

Comment: @TimCadenbach The card itself is assembled by code through library "Adaptive cards". I could guess that the problem lies in this, but from the mobile application everything looks correct :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the problem only occurs in the regular version of Teams. Everything is displayed correctly in the developer version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).